# Using rpy2 in Jupyter/IPython run_line_magic error

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook, rpy2, jupyter

In the IPython and Jupyter documentation it says that get_ipython().magic() is deprecated. But when I changed my code to use run_line_magic it is failing to push to R (see below). Might be related to this problem
https://bitbucket.org/rpy2/rpy2/issues/184/valueerror-call-stack-is-not-deep-enough

I'm on Mac Yosemite, using Anaconda with Python 2.7. I just updated both Anaconda and rpy2 yesterday. The code below is from a Jupyter notebook.

```
%load_ext rpy2.ipython
import pandas as pd

'''Two test functions with rpy2.
The only difference between them is that 
rpy2fun_magic uses 'magic' to push variable to R and 
rpy2fun_linemagic uses 'run_line_magic' to push variable. 
'magic' works fine. 'run_line_magic' returns an error.'''

def rpy2fun_magic(df):
 get_ipython().magic('R -i df')
 get_ipython().run_line_magic('R','df_cor <- cor(df)')
 get_ipython().run_line_magic('R','-o df_cor')
 return (df_cor)

def rpy2fun_linemagic(df):
 get_ipython().run_line_magic('R','-i df')
 get_ipython().run_line_magic('R','df_cor <- cor(df)')
 get_ipython().run_line_magic('R','-o df_cor')
 return (df_cor)

 dataframetest = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4],[6,3,4,5],[9,1,7,3]])

 df_cor_magic = rpy2fun_magic(dataframetest)
 print 'Using magic to push variable works fine\n'
 print df_cor_magic

 print '\nBut using run_line_magic returns an error\n'

 df_cor_linemagic = rpy2fun_linemagic(dataframetest)

Using magic to push variable works fine

[[ 1.         -0.37115374  0.91129318 -0.37115374]
[-0.37115374  1.         -0.72057669  1.        ]
[ 0.91129318 -0.72057669  1.         -0.72057669]
[-0.37115374  1.         -0.72057669  1.        ]]

But using run_line_magic returns an error

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-e418b72a8621> in <module>()
      28 print '\nBut using run_line_magic returns an error\n'
      29 
 ---> 30 df_cor_linemagic = rpy2fun_linemagic(dataframetest)

 <ipython-input-1-e418b72a8621> in rpy2fun_linemagic(df)
      15 
      16 def rpy2fun_linemagic(df):
 ---> 17     get_ipython().run_line_magic('R','-i df')
      18     get_ipython().run_line_magic('R','df_cor <- cor(df)')
      19     get_ipython().run_line_magic('R','-o df_cor')

 /Users/alexmillner/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.pyc in run_line_magic(self, magic_name,   line)
       2255                 kwargs['local_ns'] = sys._getframe(stack_depth).f_locals
       2256             with self.builtin_trap:
    -> 2257                 result = fn(*args,**kwargs)
       2258             return result
       2259 

/Users/alexmillner/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rpy2/ipython/rmagic.pyc in R(self, line, cell, local_ns)

/Users/alexmillner/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/magic.pyc in <lambda>(f, *a, **k)
       191     # but it's overkill for just that one bit of state.
       192     def magic_deco(arg):
   --> 193         call = lambda f, *a, **k: f(*a, **k)
       194 
       195         if callable(arg):

/Users/alexmillner/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rpy2/ipython/rmagic.pyc in R(self, line, cell, local_ns)
       657                         val = self.shell.user_ns[input]
       658                     except KeyError:
   --> 659                         raise NameError("name '%s' is not defined" % input)
       660                 if args.converter is None:
       661                     ro.r.assign(input, self.pyconverter(val))

NameError: name 'df' is not defined
```

Comment: It might also help to add which version of IPython/Jupyter you are using.

Comment: I updated my initial response with two workaround options at the bottom that may be helpful.

Comment: I suspect `run_line_magic()` to have dark corners (see https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/8941 for something similar with ipython 0.4.0), and we may help the ipython developers by reporting issues.

Answer (score 0):

Some discussion of the same issue with `%timeit` first, followed by workaround answers at the bottom. I'm using IPython 3.1.0 with Anaconda 2.7.10, so my observations below could be different based on version differences alone.

This is not unique to the R extension, you can reproduce this with something simpler like `%timeit`:

```
In [47]: dfrm
Out[47]: 
          A         B         C
0  0.690466  0.370793  0.963782
1  0.478427  0.358897  0.689173
2  0.189277  0.268237  0.570624
3  0.735665  0.342549  0.509810
4  0.929736  0.090079  0.384444
5  0.210941  0.347164  0.852408
6  0.241940  0.187266  0.961489
7  0.768143  0.548450  0.604004
8  0.055765  0.842224  0.668782
9  0.717827  0.047011  0.948673

In [48]: def run_timeit(df):
    get_ipython().run_line_magic('timeit', 'df.sum()')
   ....:     

In [49]: run_timeit(dfrm)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-49-1e62302232b6> in <module>()
----> 1 run_timeit(dfrm)

<ipython-input-48-0a3e09ec1e0c> in run_timeit(df)
      1 def run_timeit(df):
----> 2     get_ipython().run_line_magic('timeit', 'df.sum()')
      3 

/home/ely/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.pyc in run_line_magic(self, magic_name, line)
   2226                 kwargs['local_ns'] = sys._getframe(stack_depth).f_locals
   2227             with self.builtin_trap:
-> 2228                 result = fn(*args,**kwargs)
   2229             return result
   2230 

/home/ely/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/magics/execution.pyc in timeit(self, line, cell)

/home/ely/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/magic.pyc in <lambda>(f, *a, **k)
    191     # but it's overkill for just that one bit of state.
    192     def magic_deco(arg):
--> 193         call = lambda f, *a, **k: f(*a, **k)
    194 
    195         if callable(arg):

/home/ely/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/magics/execution.pyc in timeit(self, line, cell)
   1034             number = 1
   1035             for _ in range(1, 10):
-> 1036                 time_number = timer.timeit(number)
   1037                 worst_tuning = max(worst_tuning, time_number / number)
   1038                 if time_number >= 0.2:

/home/ely/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/magics/execution.pyc in timeit(self, number)
    130         gc.disable()
    131         try:
--> 132             timing = self.inner(it, self.timer)
    133         finally:
    134             if gcold:

<magic-timeit> in inner(_it, _timer)

NameError: global name 'df' is not defined
```

The issue is that the line magics are set to look for variable names at global scope, not at function scope. If the argument to your function `rpy2fun_linemagic` happened to coincide with a global variable name, the interior code would pick that up, for example:

```
In [52]: def run_timeit(dfrm):
    get_ipython().run_line_magic('timeit', 'dfrm.sum()')
   ....:     

In [53]: run_timeit(dfrm)
The slowest run took 5.67 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
10000 loops, best of 3: 99.1 µs per loop
```

But this only works by accident, because the interior string passed to `run_line_magic` contains a name that is found globally.

However, I do get the same error even if using the plain `magic` function:

```
In [58]: def run_timeit(df):
    get_ipython().magic('timeit df.sum()')
   ....:     

In [59]: run_timeit(dfrm)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-59-1e62302232b6> in <module>()
----> 1 run_timeit(dfrm)

<ipython-input-58-e98c720ea7e8> in run_timeit(df)
      1 def run_timeit(df):
----> 2     get_ipython().magic('timeit df.sum()')
      3 

/home/ely/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.pyc in magic(self, arg_s)
   2305         magic_name, _, magic_arg_s = arg_s.partition(' ')
   2306         magic_name = magic_name.lstrip(prefilter.ESC_MAGIC)
-> 2307         return self.run_line_magic(magic_name, magic_arg_s)
   2308 
   2309     #-------------------------------------------------------------------------

/home/ely/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.pyc in run_line_magic(self, magic_name, line)
   2226                 kwargs['local_ns'] = sys._getframe(stack_depth).f_locals
   2227             with self.builtin_trap:
-> 2228                 result = fn(*args,**kwargs)
   2229             return result
   2230 

/home/ely/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/magics/execution.pyc in timeit(self, line, cell)

/home/ely/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/magic.pyc in <lambda>(f, *a, **k)
    191     # but it's overkill for just that one bit of state.
    192     def magic_deco(arg):
--> 193         call = lambda f, *a, **k: f(*a, **k)
    194 
    195         if callable(arg):

/home/ely/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/magics/execution.pyc in timeit(self, line, cell)
   1034             number = 1
   1035             for _ in range(1, 10):
-> 1036                 time_number = timer.timeit(number)
   1037                 worst_tuning = max(worst_tuning, time_number / number)
   1038                 if time_number >= 0.2:

/home/ely/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/magics/execution.pyc in timeit(self, number)
    130         gc.disable()
    131         try:
--> 132             timing = self.inner(it, self.timer)
    133         finally:
    134             if gcold:

<magic-timeit> in inner(_it, _timer)

NameError: global name 'df' is not defined
```

One (super bad) way to get around this is to use `globals` to locate the item that is the same as the argument that was passed to your function, and then you'll have a global name for it.

For example:

```
In [68]: def run_timeit(df):
    for var_name, var_val in globals().iteritems():
        if df is var_val:
            get_ipython().run_line_magic('timeit', '%s.sum()'%(var_name))
            break
   ....:         

In [69]: run_timeit(dfrm)
The slowest run took 5.72 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
10000 loops, best of 3: 99.2 µs per loop
```

But this is very unstable, since it relies on pass-by-name in Python. If I passed an object like an integer or string, I would have to check whether it was interned or something, but otherwise couldn't find it "by name" in the global namespace.

Another way to do it that might be slightly better is to use the `user_ns` namespace `dict` that IPython stores. Then at least you're not looking at globals, and there is more stability over specific variables that have been named when assigned by the user in IPython:

```
In [71]: def run_timeit(df):
   ....:     g = get_ipython()
   ....:     for var_name, var_val in g.user_ns.iteritems():
   ....:         if df is var_val:
   ....:             g.run_line_magic('timeit', '%s.sum()'%(var_name))
   ....:             break
   ....:         

In [72]: run_timeit(dfrm)
The slowest run took 5.58 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
10000 loops, best of 3: 99 µs per loop
```

In the case of your specific R function call, I would try:

```
def rpy2fun_linemagic(df):
    g = get_ipython()
    for var_name, var_val in g.user_ns.iteritems():
        if df is var_val:
            g.run_line_magic('R', '-i %s'%(var_name))
            g.run_line_magic('R', 'df_cor <- cor(%s)'%(var_name))
            g.run_line_magic('R', '-o df_cor')
            return df_cor
```

You might also have to be careful on the return statement. You might need to use `return g.user_ns['df_cor']` or something if the result of the output conversion back to Python is to create the variable at global scope as well, rather than function scope. Or, if that variable gets created as a side effect, you may not want to return anything at all. I'm not a big fan of relying on implicit mutation like that, but it could work for you.

Comment: Thanks for this. So the fact that line magics look at global variables is on purpose? Or a bug? Should I expect this to change or no? Thanks again.

Comment: I don't know the design intentions of the Jupyter team, but my instinct is to believe that it will only look at global values, and whatever is happening in the special case where plain `magic` was somehow working for you should not be relied on. Further, I would say you should not *want* them to support looking in the local function scope. It's just a very bad idea from a programming point of view to write a function that relies on looking values up by name in a namespace like that. The better option would be to simply use `rpy2` directly if you want it as a function call instead of magic.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I was thinking I would do - use rpy2 directly. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the code example you are providing is there only to demonstrate the issue with `run_line_magic()`, but for reference I am adding a way to do the same without ipython being involved.

```
from rpy2.robjects import globalenv
def rpy2cor(df):
    fun = globalenv.get('cor', wantfun=True)
    df_cor = fun(df)
    return df_cor
```